# TinyMCE long loading times in Firefox 6

Tags: tinymce

I'm working at the website which uses really old version of TinyMCE editor to make posts. The problem is that when i load a page with an editor (i.e. making a new post) the page remains blank for 2-3  minutes and then suddenly it loads completely and editor works fine. I'm using Firefox 6 but it was like that in Firefox 4 as well and I didn't check earlier versions.

I must say right away that I can't use any other browser simply because this version of TinyMCE doesn't work in Webkit browsers the way I need it to work to make posts and it also screws up in IE and Opera. I'm not a site technical admin or programmer so I can't' install the latest version etc. The point is that I need to fix this problem in Firefox 6 with this version of the editor.

The problem doesn't seem to occur with other guys working with me so it's probably my PC specific issue. I tested this with no plugins for Firefox installed. I'm using Win 7 x64. I will provide more specs if needed.

Some details:

TinyMCE Version: 2.0.6.1 (2006-05-04)

Installed plugins:

- Tables   Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Save Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Advanced HR  Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Advanced image   Moxiecode  - Systems    2.0.6.1
- Advanced link    Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Emotions Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- IESpell (MSIE Only)  Moxiecode   Systems 2.0.6.1
- Insert date/time Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Preview  Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Zoom Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Flash    Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Search/Replace   Moxiecode   Systems 2.0.6.1
- Print    Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Paste   text/word    Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Directionality   Moxiecode   Systems 2.0.6.1
- Fullsc1reen  Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.
- Non editable   elements  Moxiecode Systems   2.0.6.1
- Context menus    Moxiecode   Systems 2.0.6.

Hope someone answers!

Comment: Dudes, in the post I told you that I can't upgrade it. Don't ask the reasons, I just can't.

Answer (score 3):

Try to upgrade you tinymce [version](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

Comment: +1 Yepp, an upgrade is not that difficult to do (as long as there are no changes made to the tinymce core). Tinymce Version 2 is pretty pretty old stuff!!!!!